# Разбить текст на параграфы

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Подскажите пожалуйста, как использовать теги в тексте, приходящие из запроса.
В book.description приходит текст в виде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div>{book.description}</div>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно что надо

Comment: через innerHTML всавьте, а не как строку и будет работать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-html-string-to-jsx

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, но это не есть хорошо [Dangerously Set innerHTML](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: book.description}}></div>
```